# From 12.04 to 14.04 on headless server

Tags: 12.04, 14.04

I got

> Welcome to Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS
>
> - Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/
>
> 10 packages can be updated. 6 updates are security updates.
>
> New release '14.04.1 LTS' available. Run 'do-release-upgrade' to
>   upgrade to it.

I am running a headless server over a vpn. Is it a good idea to run the do-release-upgrade as if something fails I could be cut out and not be able to login again?

Answer (score 0):

Yes: the upgrade process will detect that you are on a remote connection, and will open up a separate SSH server (and will notify you of this). In case of a failure, you will be able to reconnect over the other SSH connection.

Of course, if it doesn't come back up after a reboot, you will still have a problem.